# Why does the shape count in PowerPoint Notes page vary even when they all look empty?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In a long presentation, most Notes just say "Click to Add Notes". However, some `NotesPage`s have 0, 1, 2, or 3 shapes. And according to the code below and to the [MsoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msoshapetype?view=office-pia) enum, those shapes are `Placeholder`s. Why is the number of placeholders not consistent?

```vb
Sub shapes_in_notes()
    counter = 0
    s = ""
    For Each sli In ActivePresentation.Slides
        counter = counter + 1
        s = counter & ": " & sli.NotesPage.Shapes.Count & " shapes: "
        For Each shi In sli.NotesPage.Shapes
            s = s & shi.Type & ", "
        Next
        Debug.Print s
    Next
End Sub
```

Typical Output:

```
1: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
2: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
3: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
4: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
5: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
6: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
7: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
8: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
9: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
10: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
11: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
12: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
13: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
14: 1 shapes: 14, 
15: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
16: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
17: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
18: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
19: 0 shapes: 
20: 3 shapes: 14, 14, 14, 
21: 2 shapes: 14, 14, 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the program interface. Open a Notes Page, then choose **Insert>Header and Footer**. The preview shows the available placeholders. Besides the default slide and text placeholders, there are optional placeholders for **Date and Time**, **Page number**, **Header** and **Footer**. So you could have as many as 6. On the one page that has no placeholders, the slide and text placeholders may have been deleted by the user.

To distinguish them, use `shi.PlaceholderFormat.Type`.

Comment: Short version of JohnK's (good) answer: somebody deleted some of the placeholders.

Comment: The placeholders could have been deleted, but if they are unchecked in Insert>Header & Footer, they also won't show up in the count.

Comment: The source of confusion: The "Notes" appears in the "Normal" view, whether or not it has been deleted from the "Notes Page".